# How find the specifc data and update data in text file

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

```
void editProfile(String usr,String pswd,String newFname,String newLname,String newUsername, String newPassword){
        String filepath ="user.txt";
        String tempFile = "temp.txt";
        File oldFile = new File(filepath);
        File newFile = new File(tempFile);

        try
        {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile,true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filepath,"rw");
            for(int i=0;i<ln;i+=7){
                String forUser = raf.readLine().substring(9);
                String forPswd = raf.readLine().substring(9);
                String role = raf.readLine().substring(5);
                String balance = raf.readLine().substring(8);
                String firstName = raf.readLine().substring(11);
                String lastName = raf.readLine().substring(10);

                if(usr.equals(forUser)&pswd.equals(forPswd)){
                    
                    pw.println("Username:"+ newUsername+"\r\nPassword:"+ newPassword+"\r\nRole:"+role +"\r\nBalance:"+ balance+"\r\nFirst Name:"+newFname+"\r\nLast Name:"+ newLname);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login Successful");
                    
                }else{
                    pw.println("Username:"+ forUser+"\r\nPassword:"+ forPswd+"\r\nRole:"+role +"\r\nBalance:"+ balance+"\r\nFirst Name:"+firstName+"\r\nLast Name:"+ lastName);
                }
            }

            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            oldFile.delete();
            File dump  = new  File(filepath);
            newFile.renameTo(dump);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"fail");
        }
    }

     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        editProfile(username.getText(),password.getText(),newFname.getText(),newLname.getText(),newUsername.getText(),newPassword.getText());
    }
```

Im doing a page where customer can edit their personal information by entering their old username and password then new username and password. Im trying to read the old username and password to match the data in the text file and update new username and password.

There is no response when running the program, but i couldnt identify the error in my code. Any advice to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

`raf.readLine()` **reads a new line every time**. So in your `for` loop, you're getting the first entire line, lopping off the first 9 characters, and that's `forUser`, then you grab the entire second line, lop off the first 9 characters, and that becomes `forPasswd`, and so on. A single user record thus spans 6 lines and lops off a bunch of characters. I can't imagine that was your intention.

Call `raf.readLine()` once, store it in a variable: `String line = raf.ReadLine()`, then use `.substring` (you may want to read the javadoc, I'm not sure it does what you think it does), `.indexOf`, or possibly `.split` to lop that line into its component pieces.

More usually you'd do such a thing with a database, and never just eat the error (you catch `ex` and then ignore `ex`. Given that `ex` contains all the info about what happened, that's not a good idea).